# Error en consulta JPQL usando TYPE "could not resolve property"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

Soy nuevo en Spring y JPQL (y en stack overflow!), y tengo una duda de si se puede usar TYPE en una consulta JPQL cuando no estoy llamando directamente a la clase que tiene las clases hijas.

En mi caso tengo estas clases en una aplicación de alquileres de inmuebles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALQUILER")
public class Alquiler implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4036725817142449041L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include()
private Long id;

@ToString.Exclude
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ALOJAMIENTO")
private Alojamiento alojamiento;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ALOJAMIENTO")
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )

public abstract class Alojamiento implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4656346394072676126L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Getter@Setter
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    (name = "PLAZAS", nullable = false)
    private Integer plazas;
    
    @Column
    (name = "PRECIO", nullable = false)
    private Double precio;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "APARTAMENTO")
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@ToString(callSuper = true)

public class Apartamento extends Alojamiento{
    

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3561089045391062665L;

    @Column(name = "DIRECCION", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String direccion;
    
    @Column(name="ASCENSOR", nullable = false)
    private boolean ascensor;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CASA")
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@ToString(callSuper = true)

public class Casa extends Alojamiento{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4745518992755935327L;

    @Column(name = "DIRECCION", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String direccion;
    
    @Column(name = "METROS_FINCA", nullable = false)
    private Double metrosFinca;
}
```

¿Es posible hacer, mediante JPQL, que me cuente las veces que ha sido alquilado un inmueble tipo casa?

Según tengo entendido, en JPQL se pueden referenciar las clases que están unidas a la clase que estás tratando de manera "principal", pero no se si en caso así, la aplicación del TYPE es posible.

Tengo la query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Alquiler al WHERE TYPE (al.alojamiento)= Casa
```

Me devuelve:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Alojamiento of: es.seresco.alquileresCadati.model.Alquiler
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: en tu modelo nunca agregas el dato de cuantas veces ha sido alquilada, asi que ese dato no lo tienes y siempre va a fallar.

Comment: Si, eso me parecía. Al final he tenido que realizar lo que quería hacer de otra manera, con más consultas y más código.